# Facebook, possible to hide 'unlike' button once user has liked a website?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I thought i saw some code yesterday but i cannot find the link now. I wish to present the user with the like button if they havent already liked before, but if they have liked, then to hide the unlike button.

If memory serves me well, i thought i saw the line 'fb-connect'?

Comment: I would have thought that limiting your users in this way would be deeply unpopular - people make mistakes, change their minds, and change their interests.

Comment: Nice anti-pattern... (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern)

Answer (score 2):

Warning - this is a bit of a hack, use with caution.

Facebook puts its "like" button within an iframe. Here is some example code I pulled off mashable.com:

```
<iframe id="f17d5477e8" name="fe09b2668" scrolling="no" style="border-width: initial; border-color: initial; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; width: 625px; border-width: initial; border-color: initial; border-width: initial; border-color: initial; border-width: initial; border-color: initial; border-width: initial; border-color: initial; height: 23px; border-top-style: none; border-right-style: none; border-bottom-style: none; border-left-style: none; border-width: initial; border-color: initial; " title="Like this content on Facebook." class="fb_ltr" src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?api_key=1897dc5133d45afc31d3c4448572a681&amp;channel_url=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.fbcdn.net%2Fconnect%2Fxd_proxy.php%3Fa%3Da%23cb%3Df22b1d5684%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fmashable.com%252Ff218c30e6%26relation%3Dparent.parent%26transport%3Dpostmessage&amp;href=http%3A%2F%2Fmashable.com%2F2011%2F02%2F08%2Finstagram-api%2F&amp;layout=standard&amp;locale=en_US&amp;node_type=link&amp;sdk=joey&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=625"></iframe>
```

Sorry if that's a bit hard to read, copy and past it into a text editor if you need to see the whole thing.

There's two interesting bits about this:

First, its an iframe so getting DOM level access to the actual "like" text isn't possible. You can't do a test like this:

```
$('.liketext').text() == 'unlike';
```

Second, they conveniently provide a default height of 21px in the iframe source :) Note when you have already liked something the div increases in size to 62px.

Then to hide the "like" button you only need to do something like this:

```
if( $('iframe').height() > 30){ //over 30px? already "liked" it
  $('iframe').css('display', 'none');// or remove it from the DOM
}
```

You can add an event handler to the iframe's resize event if you want to hide it right after a user clicks the like button.

FWIW - this is a bit scuzzy to do but I suspect you already know that ;)